# opening files on JAVA

Tags: java, file

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3 {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
   {
      Formatter output = new Formatter( "clients.txt" ); // open the file
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ); // reads user input

      int accountNumber; // stores account number
      String firstName; // stores first name
      String lastName; // stores last name
      double balance; // stores account balance

      System.out.printf( "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",
         "To terminate input, type the end-of-file indicator ",
         "when you are prompted to enter input.",
         "On UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X type <ctrl> d then press Enter",
         "On Windows type <ctrl> z then press Enter" );

      System.out.printf( "%s\n%s", 
         "Enter account number (> 0), first name, last name and balance.",
         "? " );

      while ( input.hasNext() ) // loop until end-of-file indicator
      {
         // retrieve data to be output
         accountNumber = input.nextInt(); // read account number
         firstName = input.next(); // read first name
         lastName = input.next(); // read last name
         balance = input.nextDouble(); // read balance

         if ( accountNumber > 0 )
         {
            // write new record
            output.format( "%d %s %s %.2f\n", accountNumber, 
               firstName, lastName, balance );
         } // end if
         else
         {
            System.out.println(
               "Account number must be greater than 0." );
         } // end else

         System.out.printf( "%s %s\n%s", "Enter account number (>0),",
            "first name, last name and balance.", "? " );
      } // end while

      output.close(); // close file
   } // end main
} // end class CreateTextFile
```

but when go to file locetion and open the txt file thre is not any thing in there.i use windows and my problem is with endenging the file i think..please help me with how to write on a file in java.tnx

Comment: It works for me, at least on Linux. Trying in Windows now...

Comment: And it works for me on Windows too.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're looking at the file while the code is running, or after the program has terminated. If it's the former, then Satya's answer is appropriate - but if you're only looking at the file when the program has terminated, that wouldn't explain it.

Comment: while running the program the output will not reflect. You should terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

The output from a `java.util.Formatter` is not written immediately. Call [flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#flush()) and the waiting data will be written immediately.

```
   if ( accountNumber > 0 )
     {
        // write new record
        output.format( "%d %s %s %.2f\n", accountNumber, 
           firstName, lastName, balance );
           output.flush();//missing this line
     }
```

Comment: The code is calling `close()` at the end, which will flush the output. It's fine...

Comment: Well I tested it too, and it was fine. When you say "also checked the API" - what makes you think that closing the formatter *doesn't* flush the file output? Note that the docs say it calls `close()` on the destination if that implements `Closeable`, which a file destination will...

Comment: Current code is working fine with out any changes for me

Comment: ya offcourse. But for me after calling `flush()` only the data is reflected. @JonSkeet

Comment: You mean you don't get any output when close() is called? That should definitely flush it... I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: Exactly .. After calling `flush()` only Im getting the output. @JonSkeet

Comment: So I don't think this helps the OP, unless they're really looking at the file *while the program is running* rather than afterwards.

Comment: OP is calling `output.close();` at the end not inside the loop, also me too. So that, not getting output to file. While running the program output will not reflected in file. @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry..  misleading you earlier.

Answer (score -1):

```
java.util.Formatter will not write until flush() method is called.
    if ( accountNumber > 0 ){
    // write new record
    output.format( "%d %s %s %.2f\n",accountNumber,firstName,lastName,balance );
    output.flush(); // this is missed.
    } // end if`enter code here`
```

Comment: Why post this, it's a duplicate of the previous answer?